# How to use a type from dependence's dependence?

Tags: rust, reqwest

I'd like to use a type returned by a function in crate A that is actually defined in crate B, but crate A doesn't reexport it.

Although I can explicitly add crate B in my `Cargo.toml`, I'm not sure how to keep its version sync with the one used in crate A.

To be more specific, the type is `url::ParseError`, crate A is `reqwest` and crate B is `url`.

Comment: As you said, most probably you just need to add URL to your Cargo.toml file.

Comment: You can't really do that. Libraries are supposed to have self-contained interfaces, so you don't need the correct version of the indirect dependency. Many crates wrap types from their dependencies so they aren't exposed directly, or they re-export items, so you can import them from the dependency. Could you be more specific about your problem? The `reqwest` crate (version 0.11) re-exports `url::Url`, and it should remap all errors from `Url::parse` to its own error type. If shouldn't expose `url::ParseError` in its API surface without re-exporting it – that would be a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "official" guidelines around this issue. There was a [discussion regarding best practices](https://github.com/rust-lang/api-guidelines/discussions/176) a while back with no definite conclusion. Many crates wrap external types so they aren't exposed directly, or they re-export items. This specific issue with reqwest was [discussed here](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/pull/828) and it was decided to not re-export `url::ParseError`:

> My personal feeling is that this is somewhat niche, and so for those who don't need it, it just clutters the API. For anyone who does need to inspect for this specific error, they can add the `url` crate as a dependency.